# How do I isolate problems with ssh-add/ssh-agent provided in the msys implementation that comes with msysgit?

Tags: windows-7, msysgit, msys, ssh-agent

I have installed msysgit: Git-1.7.8-preview20111206.exe from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list  (Edit: I have also installed msysGit-fullinstall-1.7.8-preview20111206.exe, which conveniently installs to a different directory, and I am seeing the same problems with that instance).

And I am having a problem with ssh-agent, where ssh-add always reports: "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Unfortunately, ssh-add does not give me any further details on the error it encountered.  It feels like it is timing out when it tries to connect to a socket, but it does not actually admit that this is the issue, and ssh-agent acts like it is running normally.  Thinking about this combination makes me suspect a permissions issue, but I have no idea where I would look to investigate that kind of problem (and I do no see anything that I recognize as significant in windows event log).

This error message baffles me:  I have reason to believe that I could get this error message if my environmental variables were not set up properly, but I have reason to believe that I have my environmental variables set properly.  I have reason to believe that I could get this error message if my environmental variables  refer to an instance of ssh-agent which is not running, but I have exactly one instance of ssh-agent running and it matches what I see in the environmental variables.  And this is repeatable.  I have started (and eventually shut down) dozens of instances of ssh-agent, using techniques like `ssh-agent > ~/.ssh/environment; . ~/.ssh/environment`, and `` eval `ssh-agent` `` and `ssh-agent bash` and so on... and I cannot get msys ssh-add to connect to msys ssh-agent.

```
bash-3.1$ ps | grep ssh-agent
    10304       1   10304      10304    ?  500 09:01:24 /bin/ssh-agent
bash-3.1$ bash -c 'set | grep SSH_A'
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='set | grep SSH_A'
SSH_AGENT_PID=10304
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-oAFwa11048/agent.11048
bash-3.1$ time ssh-add -L
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

real    0m10.730s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
bash-3.1$ wc /tmp/ssh-oAFwa11048/agent.11048
      0       3      52 /tmp/ssh-oAFwa11048/agent.11048
bash-3.1$ cat /tmp/ssh-oAFwa11048/agent.11048; echo
!<socket >59261 060A4541-9831B739-519220DE-57936738
bash-3.1$
```

I am not concerned with scripting anything, just yet -- I believe that if I can get ssh-add working from the command line that I can script it...

And note also that the 10 seconds of real time that ssh-add uses happens before it issues the "Could not open..." message.

And, I am using a current version of windows 7, here.  And, I also have cygwin installed, but it's not in my path when I am using msys.  Task manager shows me that I only have one instance of ssh-agent running.  The ssh-agent which is running is the msys ssh-agent, and was started from msysgit's bash prompt (without anything from cygwin in path).  The ssh key was generated using cygwin's ssh-keygen, but superficial testing shows me that msys ssh utilities have no problem with the file.  ssh-agent does not give me any error messages or warnings.

I can use cygwin's ssh-agent, but mixing cygwin and msys introduces other complexities (and you can see some of that just from my description of this issue), and I am trying to get msys working without anything from cygwin.

What do I need to do to find out why the msys ssh-add does not work?  (Or: what do I need to do to get that ssh-add to work properly?)

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell you much about the why's and how's, but I can tell you what I tried and what finally solved it.
In git bash:

```
exec ssh-agent bash
```

Then (in the changed shell):

```
ssh-add
```

That worked to a degree, I only had to type the passphrase once, but I lost the normal look. After some more searching I found a .bashrc script on [this Github help page](http://help.github.com/ssh-key-passphrases/).